# What are the current factions and policy/ideological splits in the UK Conservative party?

Tags: united-kingdom, conservative-party, boris-johnson

The Johnson government had higher spending than previous Labour governments. He started by ousting a lot of the hawkish members such as Sajid Javid. Liz Truss has been a member of both this administration and Cameron's administration which was much less big on spending. So what are the splits in the party currently?

Comment: Sajid Javid is the health secretary.  He resigned as chancellor for refusing a demand from Johnson and his chief adviser Dominic Cummings that he dismiss his advisers.

Comment: I'm not giving him a pass on anything but to be fair, Johnson had only been PM for 6 months before the COVID-19 pandemic struck, and that has required a significant rise in unforseen spending over a long period of time. I don't think the colour of the party in charge has much bearing on that.